# I am not getting the lowest selling product in output.How can i correct it? in last line is output for lowest selling product.Thank you

Tags: c++, arrays

1. The program should prompt the user to enter the number of jars sold for each type.The program should produce a report that displays sales for each salsa type, total sales, and the names of the highest selling and lowest selling products.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    const int SIZE=5;
    string salsa_names[SIZE] = { "mild","medium","sweet","hot","zesty" },name1,name2;
    double number_of_jars_sold[SIZE],total=0;   
 cout << "enter the number of jars sold for each of different types of salsa\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout <<"The salsa names are :"<<"'"<<salsa_names[i]<<"'";
        cin >> number_of_jars_sold[i];
        total += number_of_jars_sold[i];
    }
    double large=number_of_jars_sold[0],small=number_of_jars_sold[0];

    cout << "The sales for each of salsa type is ="<<endl;
    for (int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        cout << salsa_names[i] << " : " << number_of_jars_sold[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "total sale is equal to" << total << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (large < number_of_jars_sold[i])
        {
            large = number_of_jars_sold[i];
            name1=salsa_names[i];
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
    {
        if (small > number_of_jars_sold[j])
        {
            small = number_of_jars_sold[j];
            name2 = salsa_names[j];
        }
    }
    cout << "The name of highest selling product is : " << name1 << endl;
    cout << "The name of lowest selling product is : " << name2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You save the value of `small` and `large` to be equal to first element of the array, which is good, but you do that **before** there are any values in the array. It contains some random rubbish.

Comment: But it is printing highest selled product names but nothing in lowest selled product.

Comment: "Random" means "it can contain a value that just happens to work". Let's say this random number happens to be `0`. Zero is *smaller* than any reasonable number of jars sold, therefore first loop will work correctly. But for the second loop, zero will never be *larger* than any value from the array, so you never set `name2` to any value.

Answer (score 1):

Edited::
you should initialize small and large to **zero** first, add an if condition before this line `if (small > number_of_jars_sold[j])`: 
`if(small == 0)`, so you will have minimum value in small variable.